# How can i compare the values in two different arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

The two arrays are not empty and are the same length. Return the score for this array of answers, giving +4 for each correct answer, -1 for each incorrect answer, and +0 for each blank answer, represented as an empty string (in C the space character is used).

If the score < 0, return 0.

The first input array is the key to the correct answers to an exam, like ["a", "a", "b", "d"]. The second one contains a student's submitted answers.

This is my code, however is not working!! can someone assist me?

```
def check_exam(arr1,arr2):
    res = 0
    
    for i in arr1:
        for j in arr2:
            if [i] == [j]:
                res+=4
            elif i=='':
                res==0
            elif j=='':
                res==0
            else:
                res+=-1
    return res
```

Example:

```
checkExam(["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"])
```

→ 6

Comment: Lookup how `zip` works in Python

Comment: You're comparing every element in arr1 to every element in arr2. Are you supposed to just compare the elements at the same position?

Comment: @Barmar I agree, with you. Should compare the two arrays by index, not compare each answer in arr1 by every answer in arr2

Comment: You don't need to put the values in `[]` when you compare them, just use `if i == j:`

Comment: `res += -1` can be simplified to `res -= 1`

Comment: Yes, the first array is the key to correct answers and second array is the submitted answer by students. I need to compare the values at the same position @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_exam(arr1,arr2):
    res = 0
    
    for i,j in zip(arr1,arr2):
        if i==j and i!="":
            res += 4
        elif i!=j:
            res +=-1
        else:
            res +=0
    return res
check_exam(["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"])

#output
6
```

for `if` checks if both numbers are equal and none of them is `""` (empty).

`elif` checks that they are different. Else is for the `""==""`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but your code does not work for this input:  (["b", "c", "b", "a"], ["",  "a", "a", "c"]) -> output 0

Comment: it should be -4 based on ur statement

Comment: The first array is correct answers and second array is submitted answers by student. So there's no correct answer and we have one blank answer. 0 for blank answers. Based on statement, the answer should be 0.

Comment: ruddy, re read what you wrote in your statement, you are explaining ur exercise a bit too late... dont post questions thinking that people will predict what you mean... just make it clear from the beginning

Comment: My bad, i'm totally sorry! I've forgot to add that statement as well!